# Content file not building in dependent project

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have an XML file in ChildProject with `Build Action` set to `Content` and `Copy to Output Directory` set to `Copy Always`. When there are no changes and I then go in and edit the XML file, save, and then build the PrimaryProject (Console Application) the XML file that is built does not contain the change.
A workaround is including the XML file as a link in the PrimaryProject but this does not seem expected behavior? It seems that a change to only a content item does not trigger a build of the ChildProject.

Note that in Configuration Manager all projects are checked to build and the normaly build process works as expected. Currently using VS 2013 Professional.

Comment: Which relation between **ChildProject** and **PrimaryProject** you have? Do **PrimaryProject** has project reference pointing to the **ChildProject**?

Comment: the `ChildProject` is a reference in the `PrimaryProject`. This issue is reproducable, perhaps a bug or I am missing something?